# Easy regex expression - taking the group up to the last comma

Tags: regex

probably simple stuff but I don't use regex that much.

Input: `c1 = 7634, c2 = a,b, c3 = 8gd_, c4 = e,78`

Desired Output:

```
c1 = 7634
c2 = a,b
c3 = 8gd_
c4 = e,78
```

Complexity (for me) - I don't know how to define it so that for c2 it takes a,b with the comma. What I currently have:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*((?:[^,].*?[^,])?)
```

trails the b.

Thanks upfront!

Comment: You could prevent crossing a comma `(\w+)\s*=\s*([^,\s]+(?:,[^,\s]+)*)` https://regex101.com/r/1IqZW5/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=\s*,\s*\w+\s*=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8QZNw9/1)

*Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` sign enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*,\s*\w+\s*=|$)` - immediately followed with a comma inside optional whitespaces + one or more word chars, zero or more whitespaces, and a `=` sign, or end of string.

Add `\s*` before `$` if there can be trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex for search with 2 capture groups:

```bash
(\w+)\h*=\h*(.*?)(?=\h*,\h*\w+\h*=|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5mcnq/6)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters in capture group #1
  -`\h*=\h*`: Match `=`, surrounded with 0 or more whitespaces on either side
- `(.*?)`: Match 0 or more of any characters in capture group #2
- `(?=\h*,\h*\w+\h*=)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have comma surrounded with 0 or more whitespaces then 1+ word characters followed by 0 or more whitespaces and `=` ahead of the current position

If your key names allow other than word characters such as hyphen, `$`, `#` etc then use this regex:

```bash
([^=,\h]+)\h*=\h*(.*?)(?=\h*,\h*[^=,\h]+\h*=|$)
```

Comment: Thanks, It's more about extracting correctly the groups, not formatting in separate lines. Can you help me with that?

Comment: ok check my updated answer

Comment: `\b(\w+)` = `(\w+)`.  `\w+` will always start matching from a word boundary position. Look out for `\h`, it is not a universally supported construct.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, your regex is working up will spots where the values are empty. Then it takes the next key-value as value.

Comment: I wrote it as per the given examples where value part was never empty. I have fixed it now.